# How to trust certificates for setuptools

Tags: python, ssl, urllib, nexus, setuptools

I've had quite a hard time trying to figure out how to get my root CA and intermediate CA trusted in order to download artifacts from my Nexus repository using setuptools Python v3.6.x.

Most, if not all, of the answers in regards to this suggest bypassing SSL. This isn't an option for me, and a huge security misstep. Also, as far as I can tell, setuptools doesn't have any builtin configuration options to allow this without specifically coding for it.

Comment: `setuptools` does indeed not have any configuration for that; you should install your self signed certs system-wide instead.

Comment: True. I'll add that setuptools doesn't try to help one figure out what it's using as a truststore.

Comment: Note: "setuptools" isn't what fetches packages; *pip* does, and it added support for system trust stores [in version 22.2](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v22-2) \(released in July 2022\), though they put users in a catch-22 by needing a 3rd-party library... which, of course, you can't download without already having it...

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: this is just how I got this to work. This is not intended to be the end all be all solution, nor do I think it should be. IMHO `setuptools` should be configurable or work differently than it does. If you have a different solution, **please post it!**

This took reading setuptools code in the file ssl_support.py. For my case I needed both certificates to be trusted. Important bits below:

```
#setuptools/ssl_support.py
...
cert_paths = """
/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
/usr/share/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
/usr/local/share/certs/ca-root.crt
/etc/ssl/cert.pem
/System/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cert.pem
/usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt
/etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem
""".strip().split()
...
def find_ca_bundle():
    """Return an existing CA bundle path, or None"""
    extant_cert_paths = filter(os.path.isfile, cert_paths)
    return (
        get_win_certfile()
        or next(extant_cert_paths, None)
        or _certifi_where()
    )
```

That hard-coded list of filepaths are extant filtered *in order* and used as an argument to a `urllib.request.build_opener` call to make the request. You need to find the *first* extant filepath and add your certificates to that file. In my case, it was `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an absolutely disgusting hack I currently use:

On Windows, use 7-Zip or something to extract [the Truststore wheel](https://pypi.org/project/truststore/#files) by hand, directly into `%ProgramFiles%\Python311\Lib`, which spoofs it to seem like part of the standard library. This is, obviously, inappropriate; so-called "site packages" which have been installed by the sysadmin actually belong at `%ProgramFiles%\Python311\Lib\site-packages`. This will also obviously need administrator access, unless you installed Python into a custom location like `%LocalAppData\Programs\Python\Python311`.

On Linux, the exact location depends on how whoever compiled Python for you set it up, but it looks like on Ubuntu you'll need to extract it **directly** into `/usr/lib/python3.10`, next to the other stdlib modules like `email`. This is, again, a "spoofed" location. Packages installed by the package manager belong in `/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages`; packages installed by Pip as Root belong in `/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages`.

Then, create a file at `%ProgramData%\pip\pip.ini` or `/etc/pip.conf` (or, if you don't have admin rights, `%AppData%\pip\pip.ini` or `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-$HOME/.config}/pip/pip.conf`), which contains this:

```ini
[global]
use-feature = 
    truststore
```

Now, when all these build tools try to do their "isolation" rituals, they'll not be *able* to hamstring themselves, and pip (which is what fetches dependencies during builds, *not* setuptools) will actually work correctly on your system and your network.

Again, this is *genuinely* an awful hack, but I don't see any better fix for it. I beg of someone to please come up with a better option, particularly one that works with tools like [build](https://github.com/pypa/build).